# Science fiction story, Boys find an alien "girl", one bonds with her mentally, plans to return with her, cave collapses

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this when I was a kid, about 10-14 years ago. I thought it was age-appropriate, but it might not have been YA/children's.

These boys are all trying to help the alien get home. One of them tries to bond while they are at a pool, sitting on towels and he becomes inseparable from her. This is a form of mental bonding. Two sentient creatures, usually two of the girl's species, become so mentally attuned that they are a mated couple and can have children, like super meditation. I think there was a very short description of the boy's POV as their brains met. The alien girl's species was in space, sending a ship at a certain time, I think. The boys were mostly helping her maintain herself until she was able to get home (I can't recall if she had a way from the beginning or not). They go into an out-of-the-way cave, which had something to do with the escape plan, but the cave they collapses, trapping the alien girl and the boy she bonded with, leaving the other boys unsure whether or not their friends got out in time.

They did not try to build a starship for her.

Comment: The aliens marry and reproduce by sitting on towels?? How does that work? The alien girl's home is in another dimension, or underground, or on another planet in space? How are the boys planning to get her home? Are they planning to build a starship? Why are they in a cave?

Comment: @user14111 That's just where they were when the topic came up. 2 sentient creatures, usually two of the girl's species, become so mentally attuned that they are a mated couple and can have children.  Like super meditation. I think there was a very short description of the boy's POV as their brains met. The alien girl's species was in space, sending a ship at a certain time? The boys were mostly helping her maintain until she was able to get home, (can't recall if she had a way from the beginning or not) The cave was out of the way and had something to do with the escape plan. No ship building